# How do epileptic seizures start?

Tags: seizure, epilepsy, pathogenesis

The basics of epileptic seizures are pretty well known. Strong, uncoordinated neural activity spreads throughout the brain, causing symptoms like confusion, hallucinations, headache, involuntary muscle movement, and many others. The further it spreads, and the stronger the brain activity, the worse the symptoms. A chain reaction of brain activity.

But what starts the chain? What makes the origination point different from the non-seizurogenic parts of the brain, leading to the onset of seizure activity, and what do the initial steps of this activity look like?